# Property env is not allowed in launch.json [VSCode]

Tags: azure, powershell, environment-variables, visual-studio-code

[image]

All I've done is initialize a template Azure Functions project in VS and when I try to set run configuration environment variables via `launch.json`, VS directly warns me that it's not "allowed".

Furthermore, even when I try to run my `.ps1` with env anyway, it doesn't work because I have something like

```
$variable = $env:AWS_REGION

Write-Host $variable
```

and the terminal output is blank, so clearly it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible directly atm see [Issue 1472](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1472)

I can however see that you are trying to start local version of azure functions, so you could declare your environment variables in local.settings.json or in profile.ps1
Edit: This just means its avalible while running the local instance of az functions, and not avalible in the integrated powershell console. the local.settings.json is also the local version of app configuration in azure and you should makre sure to include this file in your gitignore, if you are using git.

Comment: geez its been opened for 2 years and no movement

Comment: yeah, it sucks, but if you are working with az func, you should set the env using local.settings.json, and not directly.

Comment: Crazy this is still not supported. Kind of a JDI (Just Do It!)