# Cannot authenticate when debugging Azure Functions in local with VS Code

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code

I have an **Azure Function** in Python where I'm getting a secret from **Key Vault**. The Azure Function is part of an **App Service** with **Managed Identity** configured, so I do not have a Service Principal. To access Key Vault, I'm using the azure identity library and the **DefaultAzureCredential** class.

My issue is that **with local debugging of this function, credentials are not detected**. I know that the debugger use a different shell, so login environment variables are not set. I tried to specify the "env" property in launch.json but get a warning that I'm not allowed to add it, same thing if I rename it to "environment". I also tried the InteractiveBrowserCredential class to login with my user account as a workaround, but then the credentials are dismissed as incorrect to access Key Vault.

How could I setup my VS Code local debugging environment to work with the managed identity of App Service?

Here is an except of my code:

```py
import os
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, UsernamePasswordCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    vault_url = os.environ['KeyVaultUrl']
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=vault_url, credential=credential)
    access_key = secret_client.get_secret(os.environ['StorageSecretName'])
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run the function with `DefaultAzureCredential` on locally, we need to add these settings in `local.settings.json`. The json file is used to store app settings, connection strings, and settings used by local development tools. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#local-settings-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334772/property-env-is-not-allowed-in-launch-json-vscode)

For example

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",  
    "AZURE_CLIENT_ID": "42e***522d988c4",
    "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET": "Gbx2eK***ClJDfQpIjoae:",
    "AZURE_TENANT_ID": "e4c9ab4e-b***230ba2a757fb"
  }
}
```

Code

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import os
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    vault_url = 'https://testsql.vault.azure.net/'
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=vault_url, credential=credential)
    access_key = secret_client.get_secret('DBConnectionString')
    return func.HttpResponse(access_key.value,
        mimetype="application/json",)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help Jim, I'm setting it up as you said. Just one question: where do you get the client secret? From the security principal created by the Managed Identity, I cannot find it. Do I need to create a security principal manually and deactivate Managed Identity?

Comment: @Alssanro We have no way to get Managed Identity client secret. I suggest you create a security principal manually